# Generate object using Java streams

Tags: java, java-stream, maps

I have a question regarding Java streams. I built below maps.

1. One map includes country name as key and list of cities as value.
2. Another includes Continent name as key and list of countries as value.

```
List<String> inCities = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Delhi", "Mumbai", "Hyderabad", "Banglore", "Chennai"));
List<String> jpCities = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Tokyo", "Osaka", "Kyoto"));
List<String> usCities = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Dallas", "Chicago", "NewYork"));
List<String> ukCities = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("London", "Cardiff", "Oxford"));
List<String> frCities = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Paris", "Marseille", "Lyon"));

Map<String, List<String>> countryWiseCities = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
countryWiseCities.put("India", inCities);
countryWiseCities.put("Japan", jpCities);
countryWiseCities.put("USA", usCities);
countryWiseCities.put("UK", ukCities);
countryWiseCities.put("France", frCities);

List<String> asiaCountries = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("India", "Japan"));
List<String> northAmericaCountries = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("USA", "Canada"));
List<String> europeCountries = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("UK", "France"));
Map<String, List<String>> continentWiseCountries = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
continentWiseCountries.put("Asia", asiaCountries);
continentWiseCountries.put("NorthAmerica", northAmericaCountries);
continentWiseCountries.put("Europe", europeCountries);
```

Existing maps.

```
{"India":["Delhi", "Mumbai", "Hyderabad", "Banglore", "Chennai"], "Japan":["Tokyo", "Osaka", "Kyoto"], "USA":["Dallas", "Chicago", "NewYork"], "Canada":["Ontario", "Toronto", "vancouver"],
"UK":["London", "Cardiff", "Oxford"], "France":["Paris", "Marseille", "Lyon"]}

{"Asia":["India", "Japan"], "NorthAmerica":["USA", "Canada"], "Europe":["UK", "France"]}
```

I am looking for a way to build below map using java streams. What is the simplest way to achieve below output using Java streams?.

Expected output:

```
{"ASIA":["Delhi", "Mumbai", "Hyderabad", "Banglore", "Chennai", "Tokyo", "Osaka", "Kyoto"],
"NorthAmerica":["Dallas", "Chicago", "NewYork", "Ontario", "Toronto", "vancouver"],
"Europe":["London", "Cardiff", "Oxford", "Paris", "Marseille", "Lyon"]
```

1. Here key is continent name.
2. Value is list cities in countries in a particular continent.

Below is the code which I tried.

```
Map<String, List<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>>> collect1 = countryWiseCities.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey));
```

Comment: Please correct your test data code. You're only adding `inCities` for all country keys.

Comment: Updated the test data code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one thing you can do:

```
Map<String, List<String>> continentCities = continentWiseCountries.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(continent -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
            continent.getKey(), 
            continent.getValue()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(country -> 
                        countryWiseCities.getOrDefault(country, Collections.emptyList())
                            .stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList())))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

All it's doing is using an intermediate stream to join from continents to cities (through countries), then collecting cities and continent pairs.

Note that `getOrDefault(country, Collections.emptyList())` is needed because you have countries in your continent list that do not exist in your country-list mapping.

The output of the above code is something like this:

```
{
  "Asia" : [ "Delhi", "Mumbai", "Hyderabad", "Banglore", "Chennai", "Tokyo", "Osaka", "Kyoto" ],
  "Europe" : [ "London", "Cardiff", "Oxford", "Paris", "Marseille", "Lyon" ],
  "NorthAmerica" : [ "Dallas", "Chicago", "NewYork" ]
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks :). I will read more about flatMap.

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution without the intermediate stream, just using the flatMap in the value-function of the toMap-collector:

```
Map<String, List<String>> continentCityMap = continentWiseCountries.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                e -> e.getValue().stream().flatMap(
                        country -> countryWiseCities.getOrDefault(country, Collections.emptyList()).stream())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```